# Elasticsearch :: community version [ 6.4.2] secure

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Am using the community version of elasticsearch and currently its not secure by default. My requirement is to access it in a secure manner. i.e. the url should be - https://:/index instead of http::/index . Need to know the best way to achieve this . Please note that I have to use open source softwares only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard for TLS between nodes and HTTPS for outside interface on port 9200.

Using search-guard, you can also secure the access to 9200 port, using user:pass or using a certificate.

Comment: does it work on community version of elasticsearch ?

Comment: If you mean OSS version of elasticsearch, yes it works.